# Excel Index formula with two arguments and A1:Z1>value as first argument

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing

In Excel, I was trying to find the position of the first instance of a value in an unordered row that is greater than my specified value.  I have a few solutions now so I'm not asking how to do this just setting up background.

For example trying to find the first value equal to or greater than 8:
5 7 4 8 9 3 5

The value returned should be 4.

I tried some MATCH and INDEX stuff that worked well enough for ordered arrays.  But when looking for something to handle unordered arrays I found the following that works but I don't understand:

`=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:Z1>45,0),0)`

Okay here is where the questions come:

1. What is index doing?  The documentation says index takes 3 or 4 arguments.  How can it be taking only two?
2. What is with the construct `A1:Z1>45` ? How can you use the comparison operator between an array and a value? `INDEX` ends up returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`... so confused.
3. Is there some better documentation out there?  Every time I think, hey I'll give Excel a try for this simple task, by the end of it I'm back to Unix scripting for simple stuff like this.

Excel documentation always seems to be completely useless to me.  The documentation seems really dumbed down and and when seems to lie about the arguments a function can take as in the case of `INDEX`. Any direction on some good documentation would be greatly appreciated.

I'm clearly missing something here.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would 4 be the first value greater then or equal to 8? Wouldn't it be simply 8? and 5,7,and 4 are all less then 8?

Comment: @pnuts That is what MAtch does but the question is `For example trying to find the first value equal to or greater than 8` he asks for value not position... thus why asked for clarifacation

Answer (score 1):

Starting from inner to outer:

```
A1:Z1>45
```

The above returns a Boolean array representing the cells that are and are not greater then 45.

to test this you can simply type

```
=A1:Z1>45
```

Into any cell in your worksheet, and while in the formula bar press <kbd>F9</kbd>

you will see your formula turn into something like:

```
{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,.......}
```

where each Boolean is in the same relative position in the array as the cells you pass into it, and the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values represent the results of the logical test performed in this case if the cell's value is greater then 45

Next:

```
INDEX(A1:Z1>45,0)
```

this is returning the array of values for the entire column (as the index function sees it, this does not mean it is an actual column in your excel sheet) it is returning the entire array because

```
If you set row_num or column_num to 0 (zero), INDEX returns the array of values for the entire column or row, respectively.
```

Also if you re-read the docs for the INDEX function (Can Be Found At [This Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HP010342608.aspx) You should take note to the `Syntax` section of the Description. Focus on the line that says `Column_num    Optional. Selects the column in array from which to return a value. If column_num is omitted, row_num is required.`

again you can test all of this by going to any cell in your worksheet and entering:

```
=INDEX(A1:Z1>45,0)
```

and while in the formula bar press <kbd>F9</kbd>

While you could just use the formula

```
=MATCH(TRUE,A1:Z1>45,0)
```

and Array enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> using the index function allows you to simply enter it as a normal function and not an array function.

The final section of your formula is the `MATCH` function:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:Z1>45,0),0)
```

from the docs:

```
The MATCH function searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range.
```

so in your sample you are asking the `MATCH` function to return the position that it first finds a TRUE value ( TRUE is the first part of your match function)

You are searching for the TRUE value in your Boolean array generated from the index function described earlier, and the `MATCH` is simply telling you the position at which the first instance of TRUE is found A.K.A. The first cell that has a value > 45.